# Is there a way to cross-correlate two timeseries, but only when one of them rises?

Tags: cross-correlation

I'm following two timeseries: one is a setpoint, the other is the controlled output. When the setpoint rises I want the controlled output to follow quickly; when the setpoint drops, it's acceptable to have the output drop more slowly.

Is there a metric that can quantify this behaviour? Some kind of "positive cross-correlation"?

Here is a plot of the two signals I'm following. The red line is the setpoint, the orange line is the output signal.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think the concept of "cross-correlation" can be handled through copulas.

> A copula is the joint distribution of random variables U1, U2, . . .
>   ,Up, each of which is marginally uniformly distributed as U(0, 1) ([source](http://www.stat.ncsu.edu/people/bloomfield/courses/st810j/slides/copula.pdf))

Thanks to the Sklar's theorem,

> we can describe the joint distribution of $X_1$, $X_2$, . . . , $X_p$
>   by the marginal distributions $F_j(x)$ and the copula $C$
>   ([source](http://www.stat.ncsu.edu/people/bloomfield/courses/st810j/slides/copula.pdf))

Through modelling and fitting a copula, you will describe a "positive cross-correlation behavior". You can [see here a few examples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copula_(probability_theory)#/media/File:Four_Correlations.png) of copula functions.
I guess what you are looking for is perhaps a Gumbel copula and your goal would be to fit $\alpha$ ([see here](http://www.columbia.edu/~rf2283/Conference/2Models%20(1)%20Seagers.pdf) for more details)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer; I'm not sure I fully understand it though. Is there a paper or some reference you could point me to? I've tried following the presentation you linked to, but I'm not sure I understand how to apply this to my problem.

Comment: Maybe this helps? https://de.mathworks.com/help/stats/examples/simulating-dependent-random-variables-using-copulas.html